# What type of data need to be used for multiplication of sine and cosine signals in mixer?

Tags: cosine

I want to multiply sine and cosine signals(have same frequency).
I've sampled the signals and converted to digital .
Samples can range from 0 to 4096.
like 4095, 4078, 4028, 3945, 3832, etc...
I want to multiply(In IDE using C lang.) them(mixer logic) and store in another variable .

Should I use digital samples like    4095, 4078, 4028, 3945, 3832, etc...

or convert them to analog voltage values  ranging from 0 to Vref value?
using this formula
[image]

Comment: This is somewhat arbitrary what you do and really depends most on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I want to mix them and pass to LPF and filter out high frequency component

Comment: Then scaling the number doesn’t change anything does it unless you have some range you are targeting the number to fit into.

Comment: So pick whatever you like that is most convenient and clear to you and be clear on what units you are using in the result (volts, counts, etc) until you have restrictions on what device you are targeting or an audience that is requesting a result to be in some specific units.

Comment: Thanks Dan Boschen ..

Answer (score 0):

> Samples can range from 0 to 4096.

That would be a bit unusual. Most ADC will return two's complement in the range from -2048 to +2047. I suggest reading the data sheet of your ADC chip.

If you want to do this in fixed point, I strongly recommend using a fractional data type. Unfortunately most C doesn't support this natively, but almost all embedded compilers do have an extension for it since it's the "native" data type for digital signal processing.

If you can't use this, you will have to manually implement fractional multiplies with a double word length multiply and a arithmetic shift. Something like

```
inline int16 fracMul(int16 a, int16 b) 
{
   int32 c;
   c = ((int 32)a) * ((int32)b);
   return c >> 16;
}
```

where int16 is your 16-bit integer data type and int32 your 32-bit integer.

Comment: I'm using Embedded C now for demo purpose. Later all these will be implemented in processor.